# jQuery getJSON() request and nothing happens

Tags: jquery, html

I have this JSON file:

```
{
  "name": "RushaliB",
  "email" : "greg@gmail.com",
}
```

And I try to get it on a static HTML page with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>multiple languages using Jquery and JSON</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
    $.getJSON('json/main.json', function( data ) {
        $('#result').html( data.name + ' : ' +  data.email );
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My webpage is empty, I don't understand. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Where is the element with id "result"?

Comment: Where is your element with the `id` `result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no #results div. Add it!

`<div id="results"></div>`